# Avoid/warn self initialization of C++ members

Tags: c++, gcc

After having been bitten by doing something like:

```
struct Person {

  std::string first_name;
  std::string last_name;
  Person(const std::string &first_name_, const std::string &last_name_) : 
    first_name(first_name_),
    last_name(last_name)
    {}
};
```

Where the initializer `last_name(last_name)` should obviously be `last_name(last_name_)`
are there any way I can make gcc warn about such an error (is there ever any use case of initializing a member using itself ?)

Or any suggestion on a better naming convention in cases where constructor arguments are similar to the fields.

Comment: The most widespread convention is to prefix members with a letter like "m" (member) or "f" (field). Like "mLastName" or "m_last_name". This is useful not only because of this specific problem, but also because you immediately know that something is a member variable if it has the prefix. It's also less likely to get it wrong; the "_" suffix still allows auto-completion to suggest both the argument as well as the member. With a prefix this doesn't happen often.

Comment: @NikosC. when I started programming I'd use that everywhere, together with other hungarian notation kind of things like m_pfnFoo for function pointers etc. Then as an experiment I decided to get rid of it, and never missed it actually. I have the impression that when your classes are crafted carefully it offers no benefit at all.

Comment: @stijn I find it very useful especially when reading other people's code. It makes it a bit easier to understand it. Makes me use the lookup functionality of my IDE less often, which is a good thing :)

Comment: @NikosC. pretty good point about other's people code though I'd guess it falls under the 'when your classes are crafted carefully' thing: if there are so many variables used in a single scope that it's hard to figure out if they are members/globals/arguments/locals then I'd say the function is simply too large.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I avoid the issue by using the *same* name for the arguments as the members they initialise. The lookup rules specify that the name refers to the argument, when used in a member initialiser.

There is scope for subtle errors if the constructor is too complicated; but no problem if you're simply initialising members in the initialiser list.

Otherwise, GCC will give a warning about using an uninitialised value with sensible warning settings like `-Wall` (or perhaps `-Wextra`), or more specifically `-Wuninitialized`. I think there might also be a `-Winit-self` or similar, if you want to be even more specific.

Comment: +1. That is best, as it also avoids thinking two names for the same entity. Simple solutions are usually best.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: Fair enough. I always use `-Wall -Wextra`, and never encounter this issue anyway, so I wouldn't know exactly what you'd need.

Comment: I just tested, ``-Wall`` *seems* to work now, this might have changed with gcc 4.8.

Comment: I was totally unaware that lookup rules would prefer the argument in a member initializer.  If I saw `last_name(last_name)` in your code, I'd think you made an error.   I don't think having two different elements named the same is at all clear!

Comment: But, I *also* think, for *big* classes, it is better to name members differently than the local ones. For example, in my code, the members start with `_` i.e `std::string _name; int _age;` etc.

Comment: One issue I found with this is if you now enable `-Wshadow`, gcc will complain that the constructor arguments shadow member fields ...

Comment: @user1255770: That's true, but there's no problem if you only enable useful warnings.

Comment: -Wshadow have led me to find a few bugs. is arguably useful - At least it could be.. if it were not for this issue, and the issue it warns for a few other silly stuff such as the an `int index = ..;` shadowing the strings.h index() function.

Answer (score 7):

Yes; `-Wuninitialized` and  `-Winit-self`:

```
$ g++ -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -c init.cpp
init.cpp: In constructor 'Person::Person(const string&, const string&)':
init.cpp:7:3: warning: 'Person::last_name' is initialized with itself [-Wuninitialized]
```

Comment: I chuckled at "unrecognized option" :)

Comment: @jrok Hehe - I cannot spoll for the life of me.

Comment: When I use g++ (directly build object) the above error does not. Any specific reason? Even with -Wall

Comment: @kumar_m_kiran I guess you mean "the above error does not fire".  Anyway it works for me, but only using `-Wuninitialized` and `-Winit-self`, not with `-Wall` and `-Wextra`.  I guess these are extra-extra warnings...